# Do educational programmes need to be in italics within the Harvard system of referencing?

Tags: writing

I am mentioning  educational programmes within my essay and wonder if I need to have the name of the programme in italics? (For example, the *Wellmother* programme.)

Also I have mentioned a Government document, Midwifery 20/20 in the essay and wonder if this needs to be in italics?

Answer (score 2):

In general, italics would not necessarily be used just to represent the name of something. You wouldn't write "the *Marshall Plan*", so you wouldn't write "*Wellmother* programme", either.

As for the government publication, that's a different matter altogether. If the document is a "stand-alone" publication, as most such works are, then it should be italicized as if it were a book. So, this could also extend to a program if it were announced as a formal document, rather than just a policy position.